# How to get the platform independent name of a target with scons

Tags: scons

If I have this SConstruct file:

```
env = Environment()
mylib = env.SharedLibrary(target='mylib', source='mylib.c')
print mylib[0].name
```

That will print `libmylib.so` on Linux and `mylib.dll` on Windows.

Is there any attribute on the value returned from SharedLibrary that will return the original target name that I passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general relation in SCons between the name you pass in as a target and the actual target node.  Usually it's something simple as in @Brady's answer, but if you have an emitter in the builder the emitter could rename the target however it wants, or add more targets.  And sometimes you call a builder with no target, just a source, as in `env.Program('foo.c')`.  In fact, a target doesn't need to be a file!  It could be a dir, or a Value even.  So in general, I'd question why you want to do that -- there may be a better way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its possible to get the original target name, but what you can do is get the ***platform dependent*** library prefix and suffix and strip those off to get the original library name. These prefixes and suffixes are in the form of [SCons Construction Variables](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#app-variables). You'll be interested in the following:

- LIBPREFIX - static library prefix
- LIBSUFFIX - static library suffix
- SHLIBPREFIX - shared library prefix
- SHLIBSUFFIX - shared library suffix

In your case with a shared library, you could get the original name like this:

```
print mylib[0].name.strip(SHLIBPREFIX).rstrip(SHLIBSUFFIX)
```

This will work on any platform, since these construction variables change depending on the platform.